# Extraer registros de un id determinado cuya fecha más reciente sea la introducida por el usuario

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos tablas, expedientes y trámites. Lo que necesito es extraer el trámite más moderno de cada id (campo de expedientes) que coincida con la fecha introducida por el usuario (en este caso, 30-09-2021). La consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
 SELECT T.* FROM tramites AS T  
 INNER JOIN expedientes AS EX ON EX.id = T.id_expediente
 WHERE T.fec_administrativa = (
        SELECT max(T.fec_administrativa) FROM tramites AS T1 
        WHERE T1.id_expediente = T.id_expediente AND T.fec_administrativa = '2021-09-30') 
 ORDER BY T.id_expediente
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

| id | id_expediente | fec_administrativa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000228809 | 3565767596 | 2021-09-30 |
| 1000228810 | 3565767597 | 2021-09-30 |

El segundo registro no debería devolvérmelo ya que tiene otro trámite cuya fecha es más moderna que la introducida por el usuario. Debería obtener:

| id | id_expediente | fec_administrativa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000228809 | 3565767596 | 2021-09-30 |

Comment: Pásanos tu dataset con unos datos de muestra y lo que me esperarías obtener para ese ejemplo concreto. Puedes usar phpmyadmin, exportar

Comment: ¿Por qué no debería devolverte el segundo registro? Tienen `id` diferentes y la misma fecha `2021-09-30`, ¿querrías realmente el `id_expediente` más bajo de cada fecha?

Comment: No debería devolver el segundo registro por que contiene un trámite cuya fecha es más moderna que el trámite que me devuelve la consulta. Debería únicamente sacarme el id acabado en 96 por que tiene un único trámite que corresponde a esa fecha, es decir, es la máxima fecha posible de todos los trámites que tiene. De todos modos, muchas gracias por tu aportación, pero ya he conseguido resolver el problema reformulando el query.

Comment: Gracias por contestar :D

Answer (score 1):

Queda resuelto con el siguiente query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM expedientes AS EX 
  INNER JOIN tramites AS T ON T.id_expediente = EX. id
  WHERE T.fec_administrativa = (
    SELECT MAX(T1.fec_administrativa)
      FROM tramites AS T1 
      WHERE T1.id_expediente = T.id_expediente
  ) GROUP BY EX.id;
```